# Android NFC - activity is not called

Tags: android, nfc

In my app I have 3 activities A, B, and C. For activity C I've declared intent filter TAG_DISCOVERED. But when I put tag to the phone, the current foreground activity's `onNewIntent()` method called. I want nfc tag to start my C activity, no matter what activity is in foreground. If my app is in the background nothing happens at all, no activity is called.

```
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".NfcActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: show some code about the intent filter you've declared? is it in manifest?

Comment: You should avoid using the TAG_DISCOVERED intent (it is meant as a fall-back mechanism for backwards compatibility only). Instead use TECH_DISCOVERED or NDEF_DISCOVERED (whichever fits your needs).

Comment: Regarding your question: What data does your tag contain? Does it contain an AAR (Android Application Record)? If it does you need at least a TECH_DISCOVERED intent filter that maches your tag, otherwise it will trigger your MAIN activity.

Comment: I have an empty tags which I want to write data to.

Comment: Okay, then if those intent filters areall the NFC related code in your app, you WelcomeActivity's or ContactsActivity's onNewIntent() method is certainly not called due to the tag detection. Or are you withholding some code from us? I specifically think about something like a foreground dispatch that you (accidentally) enabled in your foreground activity (which is != NfcActivity). A foreground dispatch would certainly cause this but in that case I would assume that you enabled the foreground dispatch for a reason...